# lib contains undefined reference for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, xcode, clang

Trying to compile a project with luabind the following error arises:

```
ld: '__ZN7luabind6detail12property_tagEP9lua_State' in 
/usr/local/lib/libluabind09.a(class_rep.cpp.o) contains undefined reference for
architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is this a common error and easy to avoid?

Comment: What does `lipo -info /usr/local/lib/libluabind09.a` produce?

Comment: @trojanfoe `input file /usr/local/lib/libluabind09.a is not a fat file
\
Non-fat file: /usr/local/lib/libluabind09.a is architecture: x86_64`

Comment: OK, it looks to me like there is another lua-related static library you need to link against in order to resolve that symbol, which BTW is `luabind::detail::property_tag(lua_State*)`.